Model Always Classifies Images as Cats with High Confidence Despite Hyperparameter Tuning
I am trying to train a model on images using the code below. My directory structure is as follows:

The PetImages folder, which is approximately 1GB in size, is located next to my main.py script.
Inside the PetImages folder, there are two subfolders: Cats and Dogs.
Each of these subfolders contains 10,000 images of cats and dogs, respectively.

import os
import tensorflow as tf
from keras import layers
from tensorflow import keras

# === Constants for easy hyperparameter tuning ===

BATCH_SIZE = 256  # Batch size for training.
EPOCHS = 80  # Number of training epochs.
LEARNING_RATE = 5e-4  # Learning rate for Adam optimizer.

# === End of constants ===

# Filter out corrupted images
def filter_corrupted_images():
    num_skipped = 0
    for folder_name in ("Cat", "Dog"):
        folder_path = os.path.join("PetImages", folder_name)
        for fname in os.listdir(folder_path):
            fpath = os.path.join(folder_path, fname)
            try:
                with open(fpath, "rb") as fobj:
                    is_jfif = b"JFIF" in fobj.read(10)
            except Exception:
                is_jfif = False
            if not is_jfif:
                num_skipped += 1
                os.remove(fpath)
    print(f"Deleted {num_skipped} corrupted images.")

# Generate Dataset
def generate_datasets(image_size=(180, 180), batch_size=BATCH_SIZE):
    train_ds, val_ds = keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
        "PetImages",
        validation_split=0.2,
        subset="both",
        seed=1337,
        image_size=image_size,
        batch_size=batch_size,
    )
    return train_ds, val_ds

# Configure the Dataset for Performance
def configure_for_performance(ds):
    AUGMENTATION = keras.Sequential([
        layers.RandomFlip("horizontal"),
        layers.RandomRotation(0.3),
        layers.RandomZoom(0.2),
        layers.RandomBrightness(0.2)
    ])
    ds = ds.map(lambda x, y: (AUGMENTATION(x, training=True), y),
                num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
    return ds.prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

# Define Model Architecture with adjusted strides and fewer pooling layers
def make_model(input_shape, num_classes=2):
    inputs = keras.Input(shape=input_shape)
    x = layers.Rescaling(1.0 / 255)(inputs)

    # Convolutional Layers with reduced stride for some layers
    FILTER_SIZES = [32, 64, 128, 256, 512]
    KERNEL_SIZE = (3, 3)
    DROPOUT_RATE = 0.5
    ACTIVATION_FUNCTION = "swish"

    for i, size in enumerate(FILTER_SIZES):
        x = layers.Conv2D(size, KERNEL_SIZE, strides=1 if i < 2 else 2, padding="same")(x)  # Use stride 1 for first two layers
        x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
        x = layers.Activation(ACTIVATION_FUNCTION)(x)
        if i < 3:  # Apply MaxPooling only in the first three layers
            x = layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(x)

    x = layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
    x = layers.Dropout(DROPOUT_RATE)(x)
    outputs = layers.Dense(1 if num_classes == 2 else num_classes,
                           activation="sigmoid" if num_classes == 2 else "softmax")(x)

    model = keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
    return model

# Train the Model
def train_model(model, train_ds, val_ds, epochs=EPOCHS):
    model.compile(
        optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(LEARNING_RATE),
        loss="binary_crossentropy",
        metrics=["accuracy"],
    )
    checkpoint_callback = keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
        "model_best.keras", monitor="val_accuracy", save_best_only=True
    )
    early_stopping_callback = keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(
        monitor="val_loss", patience=5, restore_best_weights=True
    )

    model.fit(
        train_ds,
        validation_data=val_ds,
        epochs=epochs,
        callbacks=[checkpoint_callback, early_stopping_callback],
    )

# Check if model exists and load it for continuing training
def load_model_if_exists(model_filepath="model_best.keras"):
    if os.path.exists(model_filepath):
        print(f"Loading existing model from {model_filepath}...")
        model = keras.models.load_model(model_filepath)
    else:
        print("No existing model found, starting a new model...")
        model = make_model(input_shape=(180, 180, 3))
    return model

if __name__ == "__main__":
    filter_corrupted_images()

    # Check if a saved model exists, if yes, load it, if not, create a new one
    model = load_model_if_exists("model_best.keras")

    # Prepare the datasets for training
    train_ds, val_ds = generate_datasets(image_size=(180, 180), batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
    train_ds = configure_for_performance(train_ds)
    val_ds = configure_for_performance(val_ds)

    # Continue training or start fresh
    train_model(model, train_ds, val_ds, epochs=EPOCHS)

    # Save the trained model in .keras format
    model.save("model_best.keras")


After training a bit I am using the code below to test my model.
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image

# Load the trained model
model = keras.models.load_model("model_best.keras")

# Preprocess image for prediction
def preprocess_image(img_path, image_size=(180, 180)):
    img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=image_size)
    img_array = image.img_to_array(img)
    img_array = np.expand_dims(img_array, axis=0)
    img_array = img_array / 255.0  # Normalize to match training
    return img_array

# Predict single image
def predict_image(img_path):
    img_array = preprocess_image(img_path)
    predictions = model.predict(img_array)
    print(f"The image at {img_path} is likely a Cat with confidence {1 - predictions[0][0]:.2f}")
    print(f"The image at {img_path} is likely a Dog with confidence {predictions[0][0]:.2f}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    predict_image("Cat01.jpeg")
    predict_image("Cat02.jpg")
    predict_image("Cat03.jpg")
    predict_image("Dog01.jpeg")
    predict_image("Dog02.jpg")
    predict_image("Dog03.jpg")


This is the output:
1/1 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1s 642ms/step
The image at Cat01.jpeg is likely a Cat with confidence 0.91
The image at Cat01.jpeg is likely a Dog with confidence 0.09
1/1 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 0s 31ms/step
The image at Cat02.jpg is likely a Cat with confidence 0.92
The image at Cat02.jpg is likely a Dog with confidence 0.08
1/1 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 0s 37ms/step
The image at Cat03.jpg is likely a Cat with confidence 0.92
The image at Cat03.jpg is likely a Dog with confidence 0.08
1/1 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 0s 44ms/step
The image at Dog01.jpeg is likely a Cat with confidence 0.92
The image at Dog01.jpeg is likely a Dog with confidence 0.08
1/1 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 0s 30ms/step
The image at Dog02.jpg is likely a Cat with confidence 0.92
The image at Dog02.jpg is likely a Dog with confidence 0.08
1/1 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 0s 31ms/step
The image at Dog03.jpg is likely a Cat with confidence 0.92
The image at Dog03.jpg is likely a Dog with confidence 0.08

It consistently classifies the images as cats with nearly the same level of confidence each time.
I've tried changing the batch size, layers, and learning rate, but nothing has worked so far. What could be the problem?

You are applying input scaling two times, once in the model, and once outside, it should be made only once.

do you shuffle your training data? if cats and dogs are inputed as a separate group your model will predict the last group in your case "cats". this is the nature of the classification models. you need to mix the data before giving it to the network. hope helped.
try to add shuffle=True to the generate_datasets function
